# AngularJS ng-repeat filtering by text and multiple checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, filtering, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a set of data with attributes such as name, year, height, weight and sport. There will be two or more sport types in my data, and I would like to be able to narrow down the result of ng-repeat using checkboxes as well as a text search. As an angular noob I'm having trouble setting this up. The working code I have so far is pretty minimal. Is there a simple way of doing this? Is there a simple way of making this work with just two sports? (The two checkboxes are not currently linked to anything, they are just examples of the current html).

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
<input class="p-search" ng-model="query" placeholder="search anything">

<input class="sport-toggle baseball" type="checkbox" checked>
<input class="sport-toggle football" type="checkbox" checked>

<div class="player-card" ng-repeat="player in roster | filter: query">
    <div>player {{info}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
var rosterfy = angular.module('rosterfy', []);
rosterfy.controller('controller', function controller($scope) {
$scope.roster = [
    {
...a bunch of json data....
}
];
});
```

Comment: Please share some sample data of your json

Comment: $scope.roster = [
        {
        'name' : 'john smith',
        'height' : "5'4''",
        'weight' : '137',
        'game' : 'baseball'
        },
        {
        'name' : 'steve jones',
        'height' : "6'5''",
        'weight' : '182',
        'game' : 'football'
        },
 {
        'name' : 'jimmy bob',
        'height' : "5'11''",
        'weight' : '149',
        'game' : 'baseball'
        }
];

Answer (score 1):

Need to add ng-model on the checkboxes and input field and pass the query to filter: as an object. the properties of the query object should be same as the properties of the JSON.
HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">
   <input class="p-search" ng-model="query.Name" placeholder="search anything">

   <input class="sport-toggle baseball" type="checkbox" ng-model="query.check1" checked>
   <input class="sport-toggle football" type="checkbox" ng-model="query.check2" checked>

   <div class="player-card" ng-repeat="player in roster | filter: query">
   <div>player {{player.Name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
var rosterfy = angular.module('rosterfy', []);
rosterfy.controller('controller', function controller($scope) {
  $scope.roster = [{
   Name:"Steve",
   check1:true,
   check2:false
   },{
   Name:"Michael",
   check1:false,
   check2:true
   },{
   Name:"James",
   check1:true,
   check2:false
   },{
   Name:"Peter",
   check1:true,
   check2:true
   }];
});
```

here's a JSBin working example : [Example](http://jsbin.com/gesuciwamu/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is a good back up plan for me, but I was hoping to store the 'game' data as a string ex: {'game' : 'baseball'} and have the checkboxes match directly the string rather than {'baseball' : 'true', 'football' : false}